# Nested route not found with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here is my code

```
const AppRoutes: FC = () => {
  const {currentUser, fetchingAuth} = useAuth()

  let route
  if (fetchingAuth || !currentUser) {
    route = <Route path='*' element={null}></Route>
  } else {
    route = (
      <>
        <Route path='/' element={<OptInPage />} />
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Routes>{route}</Routes>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
}
```

OptInPage

```
const OptInPage = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<OptInLayout />}>
      <Route path='opt-in' element={<OptIn />} />
      <Route path='get-items' element={<GetItems />} />
      <Route index element={<OptIn />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
)
```

When I try to navigate to `/get-items`, the route is not found, however when I change AppRoutes to be the following

```
const AppRoutes: FC = () => {
  const {currentUser, fetchingAuth} = useAuth()

  let route
  if (fetchingAuth || !currentUser) {
    route = <Route path='*' element={null}></Route>
  } else {
    route = (
      <Route element={<OptInLayout />}>
        <Route path='opt-in' element={<OptIn />} />
        <Route path='get-connections' element={<GetConnections />} />
        <Route index element={<OptIn />} />
      </Route>
    )
  }

  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Routes>{route}</Routes>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
}
```

It does work, am I missing something?
how come when the component is nested, the route is not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code example/snippet works because it is rendering the routes and ***nested*** routes directly, as opposed to the first example/snippet's rendering of ***descendent*** routes and the root route not allowing descendent route matching.

The issue is that `AppRoutes` is only rendering a route and `OptInPage` on *exactly* `path="/"`. If you want `<Route path='/' element={<OptInPage />} />` to also match and render descendent routes (*rendered by any nested `Routes` components*) then append the `"*"` wildcard matcher to the parent route's `path`.

Example:

```
const AppRoutes: FC = () => {
  const { currentUser, fetchingAuth } = useAuth();

  let route;
  if (fetchingAuth || !currentUser) {
    route = <Route path='*' element={null} />;
  } else {
    route = <Route path='/*' element={<OptInPage />} />;
  }

  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Routes>
        {route}
      </Routes>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
};
```

...

```
const OptInPage = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<OptInLayout />}>
      <Route path='opt-in' element={<OptIn />} />
      <Route path='get-items' element={<GetItems />} />
      <Route index element={<Navigate to="opt-in" replace />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
);
```